# Oracle Apex procedure using loop

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex-5

I am trying to get the `user_id` and `group_id` for individual user.

I have used user's email in loop because so many users are there, but I need the loop should take one by one, currently its taking all mail ids like : `abinnaya.moorthy@abc.com,abinnaya.moorthy@def.com`.

Because of this the select query is not returning any value.

The select query should return the value one by one by taking the email id from loop.

code:

```
DECLARE    
    L_USERS  varchar2(1000);
    l_org_group_id varchar2(1000);
    l_user_id varchar2(1000);
    l_api_body varchar2(1000);
    l_retry_after number;
    l_status number;
    L_NOT_PROVISIONED_USERS varchar2(1000);
    l_success boolean;
    l_user varchar2(1000);
BEGIN

  FOR I IN
    (Select REQUESTORS_NAME into L_USER 
    from Request 
    where Request_Status = 'Approved' 
    and Provisioning_Status is NULL )
  LOOP
    L_USER:= L_USER ||','||I.REQUESTORS_NAME;

    select GROUP_ID INTO l_org_group_id 
    from WORKSPACE_GROUP 
    where LOWER(email)=(L_USER);

    select USER_ID into l_user_id 
    from slackdatawarehouse.users
    where lower(email) = lower(L_USER);  

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_user_id);

    if l_user_id is null then
       l_not_provisioned_users := l_not_provisioned_users||','|| L_USER;
    else
       l_api_body := l_api_body || '{"value" :"'||l_user_id ||'"},'; 
       l_users := l_users||','||l_user_id;

    end if;
  end loop;

end;
```

Help me to get the user email one by one and pass it in select query to get the groupid and user id.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do it as below:

```
 DECLARE
         L_USERS                       VARCHAR2 (1000);
         L_ORG_GROUP_ID                VARCHAR2 (1000);
         L_USER_ID                     VARCHAR2 (1000);
         L_API_BODY                    VARCHAR2 (1000);
         L_RETRY_AFTER                 NUMBER;
         L_STATUS                      NUMBER;
         L_NOT_PROVISIONED_USERS       VARCHAR2 (1000);
         L_SUCCESS                     BOOLEAN;
         L_USER                        VARCHAR2 (1000);

         CURSOR EMAIL_IDS
         IS
              SELECT REQUESTORS_NAME L_USER
                FROM REQUEST
               WHERE REQUEST_STATUS = 'Approved'
                     AND PROVISIONING_STATUS IS NULL;
    BEGIN
         FOR I IN EMAIL_IDS
         LOOP
              SELECT GROUP_ID
                INTO L_ORG_GROUP_ID
                FROM WORKSPACE_GROUP
               WHERE LOWER (EMAIL) = LOWER (I.L_USER);

              SELECT USER_ID
                INTO L_USER_ID
                FROM SLACKDATAWAREHOUSE.USERS
               WHERE LOWER (EMAIL) = LOWER (I.L_USER);

              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (L_USER_ID);

              IF L_USER_ID IS NULL THEN
                   L_NOT_PROVISIONED_USERS :=
                                         L_NOT_PROVISIONED_USERS || ',' || I.L_USER;
              ELSE
                   L_API_BODY :=
                                L_API_BODY || '{"value" :"' || L_USER_ID || '"},';
                   L_USERS := L_USERS || ',' || L_USER_ID;
              END IF;
         END LOOP;
   EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (SQLERRM);
END;
```

Comment: WHEN OTHERS? Remove it, quickly, before mama sees it.

Comment: @Littlefoot. Why ? Do you see any flaws? Is that you mama going to see ? I saw you response which doesnot making more sense to me,

Comment: Mama is here just for a joke, @XING. WHEN OTHERS is not, I'm serious, because it is absolutely **useless** here. Oracle will raise an error anyway, and you don't handle anything.

Comment: @Littlefoot It's better to have an exception handling. Am sure OP is smart enough to put required exception ? Its just a pointer that he must handle exception. Also, SO is not a forum to joke or create humour. You should always provide solution which help OP with your expertise. Your joke or absurd comments will not add more value for SO. Good luck,

Comment: Yes, you are right and I apologize. However, in my opinion, your exception "handler" is useless, regardless your last comment.

Comment: downvoted just for suggesting "when others then dbms_output"

Comment: @JeffreyKemp  You cannot do better than that as well. Enjoy your downvoting privilege. Below where answer is not good, you didnot downvoted but the solution which help OP and was accepted, you downvoted. You are great!!!

Comment: @XING, don't make it personal. We're all professionals trying to help each other. FWIW, I didn't downvote the other answer because I think it should rather be deleted. Remember, you can always edit your answer to improve it, which may then prompt me and/or others to upvote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, boy. I presume that senior members / moderators won't be too happy with this "answer", but it is impossible to put everything into a `600-characters long` comment. True, I could shorten the critic to "this is sh*t", but that won't help anyone. Though, "rules" would be obeyed. So, if it turns out that this message is deleted, sorry, everyone.

Here you go.

It is difficult to guess what you want to get as the result. You talk about `Apex`, but - what does this code have to do with it? `DBMS_OUTPUT` certainly won't work there.

Then, in `DECLARE` section, you use `3 variables` that are never used - get rid of them.

Cursor `FOR loop` is the way to do that; however, remove `INTO clause` from `SELECT`, it doesn't belong here.

`L_USER` is concatenation of all `REQUESTOR_NAME`s returned by cursor. It means that you shouldn't use it in `SELECT GROUP_ID` nor `SELECT USER_ID` statements as it certainly won't return anything (maybe *something* for the first loop iteration, but nothing for the rest of them). It looks as if you'd rather use `I.REQUESTORS_NAME`. Also, once you apply `LOWER` function to it, and then you don't - consider making it uniform.

Why do you select `GROUP_ID` at all? You never use it later.

`L_NOT_PROVISIONED_USERS` is a huge concatenation of duplicates, as you concatenate previous values with (yet another concatenation of) `L_USER`. Try to `DBMS_OUTPUT` it, you'll see.

You don't care about possible `NO-DATA-FOUND`s which might well be raised by those `SELECT`s, as - as I've already said - they won't return anything in subsequent loop iterations.

Finally, even if that `PL/SQL` finishes successfully, it won't do anything. Nobody, including you, wont' benefit from it.

So, this is quite a mess ... try to follow what I've written, make a clear picture of what you want to get as a result, go step-by-step, test frequently and - hopefully - you'll get something useful.

Comment: this is not a good answer but that's because it's not a good question :)